# implementation formula volume of a sphere with Java and JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

I have to make an implementation to calculate volume of a sphere to be checked with JUnit test, but there are some errors. The formula is correct, but when I test it, it doesn't work :

**class VolumeSphere.java**

```
public class VolumeSphere {
    public static double volsph(double j) {     
        double volume;  
        double const = 1.33;    
        double phi = 3.14;

        volume = const * phi * (j * j * j);
        return volume;
    }
}
```

and then this the test file :

**VolumeSphereTest.java**

```
import junit.framework.*;

public class VolumeSphereTest extends TestCase {
    public VolumeSphereTest(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void testSimple() {
        assertEquals(33.4096, VolumeSphere.volsph(2.0));
    }
}
```

**when I run the JUnit test, it's said "Expected: (33.4096) but was: (33.4096000005)."**

So, what should I do? Thankyou in advance for the help!

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what does that mean?  What exactly goes wrong?

Comment: **How** doesn't it work? Also, The name is PI, not PHI. PHI is another greek letter. And there is an existing constant named Math.PI. The constant const should be `4.0 / 3.0`.

Comment: Ooh, this'll be a floating point rounding error!

Comment: @JBNizet ya I used the decimal number. Result of 4/3 = 1.33. It doesn't work because when I compliled it it showed 8 errors.

Comment: It doesn't work because when I compliled it it showed 8 errors. @DavidWallace

Comment: Well, then the errors themselves will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: 4/3 is not 1.33. It's 1.33333333333... (ad infinitum). And 1.33 is a very imprecise approximation of this real number.

Comment: Yeah, but if π is 3.14, then 4/3 may as well be 1.33.

Comment: I took two numbers after coma. I already change "const" with "yow". And the another failure is expected result is not the same hmm @DavidWallace

Comment: I don't think you should change the question after people start giving you answers.  The answer about `const` being a keyword was just as correct as mine - it just dealt with a different issue.  But by changing `const` to `yow` in the question, you have made that answer wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that 33.4096 isn't exactly represented by a `double`, nor is 1.33, and nor is 3.14.  Moreover, the multiplication introduces its own errors.  Therefore, the `assertEquals` needs to be replaced by something that basically means "assert that the value is very close to what we expect".

JUnit has `assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue, errorPermitted)` for comparing doubles, which is what you should use here.

In general, `double` is a poor choice of data type for doing exact arithmetic with numbers expressed as decimals, because it stores binary representations of numbers.  If you want accuracy with exact decimals, use `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: can you give me the example for real? I mean with number of something, so I can understand it more, thank you :)

Comment: The answer already has an example: `assertEquals( expectedValue, actualValue, errorPermitted )`. The javadoc also has explanations.

Comment: You should write something like `assertEquals( 33.4096, volume, 0.00001 );` or similar, after you've calculated the volume, depending on how much inaccuracy is acceptable to you.

Comment: oh my God it's true, when I compile the JUnit test, it's said "Expected: (33.4096) but was: (33.4096000005). How?

Answer (score 4):

`const` is a keyword and can't be a name of a variable - pick a different name for your variable.

Comment: -1 const is not a keyword in Java.  Why would someone upvote this?

Comment: @DavidWallace it's a keyword but its [not used](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)

Comment: My apologies.  I take it back.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the answer isn't exactly the value you let the JUnit test compare to. The answer is 33.409600000000005 instead of 33.4096. To remedy this, you could use `assertEquals(33.4096, VolumeSphere.volsph(2.0), 0.0001);`.

This will allow all answers within a difference of 0.0001 around 33.4096. Therefor in this case it will allow 33.4095 to 33.4097.

Also, instead of using `double phi = 3.14`, you could use `Math.PI`, which inserts the more significant value of constant pi.